# Which rep range contributes to the most hypertrophy of calves?

Tags: bodybuilding, hypertrophy, calf

I've watched videos of two big bodybuilders, Jay Cutler and Hunter Labrada. Both bodybuilders start with the premise of "your calves are being used all day long...". [Jay Cutler](https://youtu.be/zf5GJrwYGc8?t=16m20s) finishes with

> You got to train them like every other body part. If I'm doing high repititions when I walk, why would I do high
>   reptitions in the gym? (Demonstrates with 10 reps)

[Hunter Labrada](https://youtu.be/r7HmshZvys8?t=49s) finishes with

> It takes more stimulation and reps to train than any other muscle. (Demonstrates with 30 reps)

Which bodybuilder should I believe? Jay Cutler is a far more successful bodybuilder than Hunter Labrada because Jay has been Mr. Olympia 4 times, but both guys look much better than I'd ever hope to be.

Comment: I'm sure we _could_ focus on calves here, but [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/should-rep-range-be-determined-by-muscle-fiber-composition?rq=1) is similar and has an answer already.

Comment: Be careful using professional bodybuilders as your standard.  Although they train hard, most use anabolic steroids, making it easier for them to achieve massive and ripped physiques.

Comment: The guys I know with the biggest calves are or were competitive cyclists and speed skaters.

Answer (score -1):

There are unfortunately few reliable studies about rep range for hypertrophy, but I have always heard that calves require more than average, with ranges from 15-30 based on weight used in that set.